# if $\sup(S) = \infty$, then there is a sequence $s_n \in S$ such that its limit is $\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

This is a question on a practice midterm. It seems intuitively true (otherwise $S$ would seem to have a finite upper bound), but I'm unsure of how to rigorously prove it. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Write down the definition of "sup is infinity" and the definition of "limit is infinity" and see if you can conclude one from the other. Expect the argument to be straightforward since it's a midterm exam question.  Edit your question here to show your work if you need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\sup S=+\infty$, there is an element of $S$ greater than $1$. Call it $x_1$. And since $\sup S=+\infty$, there is an element of $S$ greater than $2$. Call it $x_2$. And so on. Can you take it from here?